# Populating the value field of a textarea using Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2, select2-rails

In the `select2` [example for tagging](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), the dev dynamically generated the `value` of the corresponding `input` element (#e12).  Whenever a user selects or unselects an option, the `value` of the input changes instantly.

```
//JS for example
$("#e12").select2({tags:["red", "green", "blue"]});

//Corresponding html
<input type="hidden" id="e12" value="brown,red,green" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">

//Corresponding html if the user unselects "brown"
<input type="hidden" id="e12" value="red,green" tabindex="-1" class="select2-offscreen">
```

I want to do the same for a `textarea` element.  However, when I add tags as shown in their example, the `value` of my `textarea` does become dynamically changed.

Full JS is in this pastie: http://pastie.org/private/0uhoyqiqauhcx40av5j68g

```
//My JS, truncated.  
$(".addPeopleToCohort").select2({
        tags: ["David Baldwin", "Gonzo Loopy", "Eric Baldwin", "Terry Stark"],
        ...
//Corresponding HTML, note the lack of a value field
<textarea class="addPeopleToCohort select2-offscreen" name="students" tabindex="-1">
```

What should I do to get the `textarea` to have a dynamically updated `value` field?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly,
see if helps you:

http://jsfiddle.net/q75D9/2/

```
$('#select-data').change(function(){
   var insert = $( "#select-data option:selected" ).val();
   $('#insert-data').val(insert);
});
```

hug.

Comment: I'll try your method, although it doesn't look like the example requires an explicit function.  I added more context to my original question too.  Thanks for helping